# Python match two dataframes by numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, each has longitudes and latitudes. Df1 are small places with coordinates, and df2 are city names with coordinates of city centers. I would like to assign a city name to each location in df1, by finding the closest coordinates in df2.

`df1` looks like:

```
location     lng       lat          
a            117        33
b            114        32
c            101        23
d            131        46
```

`df2` looks like:

```
city         citylng   citylat
X             100       20
Y             130       40
Z             115       30
```

A possible criteria may be (1) calculate the difference between coordinates and sum the difference. (2) choose the city with the smallest difference sum. For example, the difference between the coordinates of `location a` and `city Z` is `abs(117-115)+abs(33-30)=5`, while `(a,X)= abs(117-100)+abs(33-20)=30` and `(a,Y)= abs(117-130)+abs(33-40)=20`. So as a result, we have:

```
location     city       
a            Z
```

Is there a way to code this in Python?

Comment: Are you asking about if pandas has the functionality to immediately do this based on a function? Or do you want a solution where we iterate through the data points of df1 comparing the sum of absolute distances to every point in df2 to find the minimum?

Comment: I am thinking are there any functions like fuzzy matching which picks the closest rows authomatically?

Answer (score 3):

We can do it with `numpy` broadcast and `argmin`

```
s1=df1.lng.values
s2=df1.lat.values
idx=np.abs(s1-df2.citylng.values[:,None] + s2 - df2.citylat.values[:,None]).argmin(axis=0)
df1['city']=df2.city.iloc[idx].values
df1
  location  lng  lat city
0        a  117   33    Z
1        b  114   32    Z
2        c  101   23    X
3        d  131   46    Y
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I am looking for. I do get the `idx`, but all rows have the same number. Then the resulting `city` column is all `nan`. Are there any reasons why this happens?